# Exportação jQuery DataTables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Possuo uma tabla e  utilizo o DataTables, estou utilizando a funcionalidade nativa de exportação e dar um hide nas colunas o meu código esta mais ou menos assim:

```
"buttons": 
[
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 
    { 
        extend: 'colvis', 
        text: '+ Colunas' 
    }
],
"columnDefs": 
[
    {
        "targets": [ 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21 ],
        "visible": false,
    }
]
```

só que quando o usuário vai exportar exporta todos os dados ate as colunas que não estão visíveis gostaria de saber se é possível e se tem como alguém me ajudar para que só seja exportado os dados e colunas que estão visíveis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente com o parâmetro `columns: ':visible'` na opção **exportOptions** do botão, dessa forma:

```
"buttons": 
[
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 
    { 
        extend: 'colvis', 
        text: '+ Colunas',
        exportOptions: {
           columns: ':visible'
        }

    }
],
"columnDefs": 
[
    {
        "targets": [ 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21 ],
        "visible": false,
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

para fazer isso basta usar a propriedade exportOptions do DataTable:

```js
"buttons": [
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'copyHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                    { 
                        extend: 'colvis', 
                        text: '+ Colunas' ,
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                ],
```

Fonte: [DataTables](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/columns.html)